# image loading time from server using glide

Tags: android, image, loading, android-glide

i am using glide to load image from a url and show in image view . but glide takr too much time to load image into image view even in good network connection

```
       RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
    options.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);
    options.getOnlyRetrieveFromCache();

    Glide.with(context).load(Api_Client.Image_URL+IMAGES.get(position))
            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Log.e("failed",e.toString());
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    return false;
                }
            })
            .apply(options)
            
    )
            .into(imageView);
```

Comment: remove customized RequestOptions

Comment: i removed request option still loading time is too much

Comment: isn't server's problem? check image loading time in browser or test another images

Comment: in browser image loading immediate. its taking time on android

Comment: add  .disallowHardwareConfig() befire .into(..)
and add "?" in end of your image url

Comment: add .disallowHardwareConfing but no effect . same as before time taking